# Drag event does not work in RN with Mapbox

Tags: react-native, expo, mapbox

I have a React Native project with Expo that uses @rnmapbox/maps. Within a screen of my app, I display the user's location on the map with a marker. If a user wants to drag the marker and position it to another point on the map, they can do so. What the app expects is to save the new coordinates in a state using the onDragEnd event. However, despite being able to drag the marker, for some reason, this function is not triggered. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
 <MapboxGL.MapView scaleBarEnabled={false} style={{ flex: 1 }} styleURL={...}>
  <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation id="userMarker"
  anchor={{ x: 0.5, y: 1 }}
  draggable={true}
  onDragEnd={(payload) => {

   console.log('works?');
                            
   //use state
   setterLocation(
    payload.geometry.coordinates[0],
    payload.geometry.coordinates[1]
   );
  }}
  coordinate={[locationView.lng, locationView.lat]}>
  <View className="py-2 px-3 rounded-full bg-neutral-800 flex flex-row justify-center items-center">
   <Text className="text-white text-base text-center mx-2">
      ...
   </Text>
   <Feather name="map-pin" size={24} color="white" />
  </View>
</MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
  <MapboxGL.Camera
   centerCoordinate={[locationView.lng, locationView.lat]}
   zoomLevel={14}
   pitch={30}
   animationMode="flyTo"
 />
</MapboxGL.MapView>
```

I will continue investigating why the function isn't being triggered. I'm not handling complex states or anything similar that might be causing this issue. If I discover anything or find a solution, I'll share it here